# Chrome bug with fixed background and parallax

Tags: google-chrome, background-image, parallax

I have 2 `<section>`s with big `background-image`. In the first one, I load `<li>`s by clicking on the button. While they fade in, the second `<section>`'s background is "jumping" but only in chrome.
I tried the hack `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`; but it just made it worse. If I set the `background-attachement: scroll;` it works, but no parallax then on the background-image. Got any ideas?

**Example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/u92RS/4/embedded/result/

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @123 it was the latest one, dunno version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug (what a surprise). It works fine now in the latest Chrome Canary version.